# How can I send from my app using WhatsApp

Tags: android

I've WhatsApp installed in my mobile, and want to snd WhatsApp message from my app using the below code, but I'm getting that `WhatsApp is not installed in your phone`?!

```
        whasappBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val packageManager = it.context.packageManager
            val text = "Hi, we are sending you frm XYZ company."
            val url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$mobile" // &text=$text"
            val whatsAppIntent = Intent().apply {
                setPackage("com.whatsapp")
                action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                data = Uri.parse(url)
                type = "text/plain"
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
            }
            try {
              //  if (whatsAppIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
              //      it.context.startActivity(whatsAppIntent)
              //  }
                startActivity(whatsAppIntent)
              //  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(whatsAppIntent, text));
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp is not installed in your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the stack trace

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard It is `Kotlin.Unit`, I got it by running `Toast.makeText(this, e.printStackTrace().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Comment: `e.printStackTrace().toString()` is not how you get a stackTrace. check in your logcat for the errors.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I run it in the mobile, unfortunately I've issue with my cable so have to install it in my mobile as separate file.

Comment: in that case @HasanAYousef you have to do this : 
`Toast.makeText(this, e.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void openWhatsApp() {
    String smsNumber = "7****"; // E164 format without '+' sign
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error/n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;    
    }
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I send for a group, if I have it `uniqueId` instead of having single mobile number?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write the same accepted answer is:

```
        whasappBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val sendIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN").apply {
                setPackage("com.whatsapp")
                type = "text/plain"
                action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                putExtra("jid", "$mobile@s.whatsapp.net")
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi, we are sending you frm XYZ company.")
            }
            try {
                startActivity(sendIntent)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp is not installed in your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```